# Запись файла в шаблон excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Есть класс для записи структуры данных в новый файл excel, приведен ниже.
Нужно добавить возможность записи в шаблон.

Т.е. сейчас приходит список листов для записи в файл (Map> ofd) где ключ - название листа, а значение - список строк с данными.

И все это записывается в новый файл эксель.

Я хочу записывать эти же данные в шаблон, в котором несколько листов с данными уже есть.

```
public class WriteToExcel {

    public String writeResult(String path, Map<String, List<String[]>> ofd){
        SXSSFWorkbook newBook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
        Sheet newSheet = null;
        //в цикле получаю список названий листов и передаю их далее для записи
        for(String sheetName: ofd.keySet()){
            newSheet = newBook.createSheet(sheetName);
            writeSheet(newSheet,ofd.get(sheetName));
        }
        String pathResult = path  + "\\ИМЯ.xlsx";

        saveBook(newBook, pathResult);
        return pathResult;
    }
    //метод для сохранения результата
    private void saveBook(SXSSFWorkbook newBook, String path) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
            newBook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // запись данных в эксель
    private void writeSheet(Sheet sheet, List<String[]> list){

        Row row = null;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            String [] rowData = list.get(i);
            row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.get(0).length; j++) {
                try { //Чтобы числа были записаны в xml как числа а не как текст
                    row.createCell(j).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(list.get(i)[j]));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    row.createCell(j).setCellValue(list.get(i)[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Так записывайте, вопрос то в чем?

Comment: у тебя осталась программа? У меня похожая задача. Можешь поделиться исходниками?

Comment: прости, все осталось на старой работе.

Comment: Очень прошу, посмотри, я тут описал подробно вопрос [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836024/apache-poi-%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-excel-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Comment: Может будут советы какие-то? Я уже честно не знаю, что делать.