# Apache POI Считать таблицы из одного документа Excel и поместить в другой

Tags: java, apache, excel, poi

Суть задания. Есть несколько документов Ecxel (xls) Данные из них нужно собрать и поместить отдельный файл (xls).

Не могу разобраться как получать данные из заданного места, например, из отдельных 40 ячеек. И не могу их переместить в общий документ.

Все это должно Работать сразу с несколькими файлами. То есть сканировать папку с документами и сводить все документы в один общий.

Код для чтения по строкам

Тут я использую цикл for и получаю ячейки по строкам. Как мне полученные данные перенести в отдельный файл?

Нужно создать может ArrayList?

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/Maks_Taranuyk/Desktop/Doc/1 3.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        int starRow = 2;
        int endRow = 27;

        for (int i = starRow + 1; i < endRow; i++) {
            System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(8).getCell(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код и уточните, что именно не получается.

Comment: Я испробовал много разных вариаций кода. Пробовал и через Iterator<> ячейки перебирать. Но в таком случае получаю все строки в таблице. А мне нужны лишь некоторые ряды и столбцы. Я не совсем понимаю как здесь код вставлять правильно.

Comment: @МаксимТаранюк , в вопросе указано как переместить ячейки, и судя по коду, Вы их уже получаете. У ячейки получите значение, и поместите в `ArrayList` , потом используйте его при создании. А вот какие нужно считывать некоторые ряды, в вопросе не приведено.